# Help with an integral (Hypervolume of a $4 \text{-D}$ Sphere)

Tags: calculus

**Help with this integral**

I was trying to derive the formula for the volume of a $4\text{-D}$ Sphere ($3$-sphere) so I found this integral, but I don't know exactly how to reach the final result.

$$ \int _ { - r } ^ r \frac 4 3 \pi \left( \sqrt { r ^ 2 - x ^ 2 } \right) ^ 3 \mathrm d x = \frac 1 2 \pi ^ 2 r ^ 4 $$

I would be glad if you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type up your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the equation of the 3-ball of radius $r$ is given by
\begin{align}
S_R=\{(x_1, \ldots, x_4)\mid x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2\le R^2\}.
\end{align}
Using "cylindrical coordinates", we see that that
\begin{align}
S_R =\{ (x_1, \rho, \theta, \phi)\mid -R\le x_1\le R, 0\le \rho\le \sqrt{R^2-x_1^2}, 0\le\theta\le 2\pi, 0\le\phi\le \pi\} .
\end{align}

Finally, we see that
\begin{align}
\text{Vol}(S_R) =&\ \int_{S_R}dV = \int^{R}_{-R} dx_1\int_{\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2}\le \sqrt{R^2-x_1^2}} dx_2dx_3dx_4\\ =& \int^R_{-R} dx_1 \left(\text{Vol}(\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2}\le \sqrt{R^2-x_1^2}) \right)\\ =& \int^R_{-R} dx_1\ \frac{4}{3}\pi (\sqrt{R^2-x_1^2})^3.
\end{align}

It remains to integrate the integral. Observe
\begin{align}
\int^R_{-R} dx_1\ \frac{4}{3}\pi (\sqrt{R^2-x_1^2})^3 =&\ 2\int^R_{0} dx_1\ \frac{4}{3}\pi (\sqrt{R^2-x_1^2})^3\\
=&\ \frac{8\pi}{3} \int^R_0 (R^2-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}\ dx\\
=&\ \frac{8\pi}{3}R \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 (R^2-R^2\sin^2\theta)^\frac{3}{2}\cos\theta\ d\theta\\
=&\ \frac{8\pi}{3}R^4 \int^{\pi/2}_0 \cos^4\theta\ d\theta = \frac{8\pi}{3}R^4\frac{3\pi}{16} = \frac{1}{2}\pi^2R^4.
\end{align}